# Calling Thread.Sleep() inside lock statement in .net

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, locking

I was wondering if a call to Threa.Sleep on a thread that already acquiered a Monitor will release the lock before going to sleep:

```
object o = new object();
Montior.Enter(o);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Monitor.Exit(o);
```

While the thread is suspended - can other thread acquire `o`?

Comment: Calling, Thread.Sleep inside a lock is a recipe for an unresponsive application.  You should perform the minimal amount of work inside a lock as possible, otherwise other threads waiting on the resource will pile up waiting to acquire the lock.

Comment: @JaredShaver Except in a whole bunch of cases such as locking around sending data to a piece of hardware that gets data from loads of different threads but will crash if you send data too quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the lock will not be released if you Sleep.

If you **want** to release it, use `Monitor.Wait(o, timeout)`; further, you can also use this to signal from another thread - another thread can use `Monitor.Pulse[All]` (while holding the lock) to wake the waiting thread earlier than "timeout" (it will re-acquire the lock in the process, too).

Note that whenever using Enter/Exit, you should consider using try/finally too - or you risk not releasing the lock if an exception happens.

Example:

```
bool haveLock = false;
try {
    Monitor.Enter(ref haveLock);
     // important: Wait releases, waits, and re-acquires the lock
    bool wokeEarly = Monitor.Wait(o, timeout);
    if(wokeEarly) {...}
} finally {
    if(haveLock) Monitor.Exit(o);
}
```

Another thread could do:

```
lock(o) { Monitor.PulseAll(o); }
```

Which will nudge any threads currently in a Wait on that object (but does nothing if no objects were waking). Emphasis: the waiting thread still has to wait for the pulsing thread to release the lock, since it needs to re-acquire.

Comment: But the Pulse method will automatically (and atomically...) release the lock from the object, right

Comment: @PiniSalim no, `Pluse` explicitly does **not** release the lock - the other (waiting) thread is moved to the *ready* queue, and obtains the lock and continues only when the lock is released by `Monitor.Exit` - i.e. when it leaves the `lock(o) {...}` part of the "Another thread could do:" example.

Comment: @PiniSalim or from MSDN, emphasis mine: "Upon receiving the pulse, the waiting thread is moved to the ready queue. When the thread that invoked Pulse **releases the lock**, the next thread in the ready queue (which is not necessarily the thread that was pulsed) acquires the lock."

Answer (score 10):

No, the thread won't release the `lock` before suspending/sleeping

and no other thread will be able to acquire `o` until the sleeping thread wakes up and releases the locked object

Answer (score 7):

No, between `Enter` and `Exit`, no other thread can take the lock whatever you do inbetween.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, calling Thread.Sleep in the middle of a lock block would cause the locking thread to lose the lock (i.e context switch).
I ran the following program:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(c1.DoSomthing);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(c2.DoSomthing);
        t1.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        t2.Start();
    }
}

class Class1
{
    object m_objSyncLock = new object();
    ManualResetEvent m_objSleep = new ManualResetEvent(true);

    public void DoSomthing()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(m_objSyncLock);
            int i = 1; //break point here
             Thread.Sleep(565);
            i++; //break point here
        Monitor.Exit(m_objSyncLock);
        }
    }
}

class Class2
{
    object m_objSyncLock = new object();

    public void DoSomthing()
    {
        lock (m_objSyncLock)
        {
            int i = 1;    //break point here           
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

> Add break points to lines 30, 32, 46 and notice that line 32 occur 1st, then line 48, and only then line 34.
>   Doesn't this mean that the Thread.Sleep call made me lose my lock?

Moreover, when using ManualResetEvent.WaitOne instead of Thread.Sleep, the executing thread didn't lose exclusivity (except the switch to ManualResetEvent itself).

I'm no guru but this simple test show that Thread.Sleep might make you lose the lock while using ManualResetEvent.WaitOne keeps the lock code block in sync.

Comment: I cant figure out your point properly because its hard to find the line numbers. If you can add a comment on each line you refer saying what happens to the debugger it will be helpful to figure out your point.

Comment: Ah now I see where you got wrong. You have created 2 objects for locking. That wont do any thing. (If you have "new" in 2 places it means 2 objects). If you want to lock properly you should lock on the same object.

Comment: @HimeshSameera indeed!