# Why Thread.Sleep synchronizes threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Why without `Thread.Sleep` threads will work asynchronously (1), and with it - synchronously (2)?

[image]

```
class A
{
    static object locker = new object();

    static void M0()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            lock (locker)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Secondary");
                //Thread.Sleep(100);
            }    
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(M0);
        Thread t = new Thread(ts);
        t.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            lock (locker)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Primary");
                //Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454472/calling-thread-sleep-inside-lock-statement-in-net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both ways are working asynchronously, after all, you've got 2 threads.

When you start the thread and don't have the sleep it executes so quickly that it manages to output 5 `Secondary` lines within its allocated timeslice.

The `Sleep` call slows everything down, and because you are sleeping for a period that is reasonably large (compared to a threads timeslice) it gives the appearance of the threads running in step.

However, this is just luck. There's nothing to stop the thread scheduler deciding to suspend `M0` just before it enters the `lock` for a period of time that allows the main thread to fully execute its loop.